# Implement a strange automaton

Tags: code-golf, cellular-automata

I was playing around with cellular automaton and I found one that had some interesting behavior.  Here's how it works:

It reads a binary string from left to right, if it encounters a `1` followed by `2` other values it will append a `0` to the result and continue reading.  If it encounters a `0` (or there are less than 3 values left) it will append the current value and a `1` and continue reading.  At the end of the string it will append a single `1` to the result.

Here's a worked out example of one generation

```
01011111
^
```

We first encounter a `0` so we append `01` to our result

```
01011111
 ^
01
```

Now we encounter a `1` so we append a zero and skip the next two values

```
01011111
    ^
010
```

We encounter another `1` so we do the same

```
01011111
       ^
0100
```

We now have another `1` but not enough space to jump so we append the current cell and a `1` (in this case `11`)

```
01011111
        ^
010011
```

We are at the end so we append a single `1` and terminate this generation

```
01011111
        ^
0100111
```

## Task

Given input in any reasonable format you must create a function or program that computes one generation of the automaton.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) question so answers will be scored in bytes, with fewer bytes being better.

## Sample implementation

Here is a sample implementation in Haskell (defines a function `d`, but the program prints a iterations indefinitely):

```hs
d('1':_:_:x) = "0" ++ d x
d(a:x) = a:'1':d x
d x = "1"
r x = x:map d(r x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P0VD3VDdKh4IKzQVbBWUDJQUtLUVUhQquFI0EiFiiVYgJWAhhQqQGkMlriIwq8IqN7FAIUUDyNP8n5uYmWdbUFoSXFKkUpqXk5mXWqxSBDTQ0MDAUOk/AA)

Comment: In your question you state *We now have another 1 but not enough space to jump so we append the current cell and a **1 or 11***. Is it 1 or 11?

Comment: Ah its just an `11` thats a case where english could use parens read it as  `(we append the current cell and a 1) or 11`  I'll try to make this clearer with an edit.

Comment: So then if we have a `10` it should print `11011`?  I think a few more test cases would be helpful

Comment: @nmjcman101 That is correct.  The sample program is comprehensive.

Comment: @WheatWizard my fault should have seen the link!

Comment: @WheatWizard I would appreciate a clearer explanation, perhaps a table, of the rules

Comment: "an" automat*on*. SCNR.

Comment: I don't believe this is actually a cellular automaton, but feel free to enlighten me with a definition saying it is.

Comment: @feersum Indeed, it doesn't preserve number of cells. It's a [finite-state transducer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_transducer).

Answer (score 7):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>26</s> <s>22</s> 21 bytes

Thanks to @CowsQuack for 4 bytes by combining regexes! And @ØrjanJohansen for another byte with some regex combinations.

```
Ó1../3
Ó./&1
Ó31/0
A1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///BkQz09fWOuw5P19NUMgZSxob4Bl6Ph//@GBgaGBgA)

Uses substitute multiple times and appends a 1 at the end.  Nothing too fancy.  I have a version that remaps `1` and `0` in insert mode to get the desired effect, but it's quite a bit longer.

(Multiple replacement version: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/3/TwxsiCw5MN9fT0jfVTuQ5P1tNXMwRSxob6BkC@o@H//waGBgaGAA))

Comment: The second and third regexes can merge into `Ó1ü0/&1` (`ü` is `\|`)

Comment: @Cowsquack genius!

Comment: It's even shorter to do `Ó./&1` followed by `Ó31/0`.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), 56 bytes

Takes input as an array of characters. Returns a string, or the number `1` if given an empty array.

```js
f=([v,...a])=>v?(+v&&a[1]?a.splice(0,2)&&'0':v+1)+f(a):1
```

#### Demo

```js
f=([v,...a])=>v?(+v&&a[1]?a.splice(0,2)&&'0':v+1)+f(a):1

console.log(f([...'01011111']))
console.log(f([...'10']))
```

#### Animated version

Examples of stable inputs: 0101, 010011111

```js
f=([v,...a])=>v?(+v&&a[1]?a.splice(0,2)&&'0':v+1)+f(a):1

s = '1';
setInterval(_=>o.innerHTML=s=''+f([...s]), 200)
```

```html
<input oninput="s=this.value" value="1" />
<pre id=o style="font-size:32px"></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 89 bytes

```python
x=input()
y=0
k=[]
while x[y:]:v=1-x[y]*(y<len(x)-2);k+=[x[y]]*v+[v];y+=3-2*v
print k+[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYjbCoQgEEDf/YoevSSk@1bNlwzzGCSGK2HmfL1tsBwOHE7msn@T771BSPkqUgmGSURAEvcejm1oyDPNFZz9FWnJ67El2ZT1aokG8L2kq8FKCxv4WK@ryGdIZYgGHfWO0@jG1z/0AA)

-4 bytes thanks to Rod
-6 bytes thanks to ovs
-1 byte thanks to micsthepick

Comment: `[0]if v else[x[y],1]`can be rewritten as `[[x[y],1],[0]][v]`, but you can invert the `v` value  to reach [96 bytes](https://tio.run/##PchBCsMgEEDRvafoUmOEaHdN5yTDLAINRAxTKdY4p7cESvj8zctStjeH3htEzt@ijRKYVAIkdWxxX2/y3FfWzTwqeKcbCi38utQFMycLeDoN1WKlWSzcXRiqyp/IRSeLnkzvOI1@PP9HPw)

Comment: [90 bytes](https://tio.run/##LYjbCoQgEEDf/YoevSSkvVXzJcM8BolhsrjmfL27QRwOHE7mclzJ994gpPwtUgmGSURAEvcRzn1oyAstFZz9F2nJ27kn2ZT1ao0G8Lmkq8FKKxuYrddV5E9IRUaDjlTvOI1ufHyhHw)

Comment: Parentheses are not needed for print statement in python 2, so you can save one byte

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 88 bytes

```python
I,r=input(),[]
while I:a=I[0]and len(I)>2;b=a<1;r+=[I[0]]*b+[+b];I=I[a*2+1:]
print r+[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYoxCsMwDAD3vEJjEnmIPcZ1d71BaLBpIIagGuNS@nq3IUPhuOWufNr@VNc7mRqyllcbJ8MyvPd8bEBrDMSLRH3AselI0935FOLN@oqBzyRzQsYknn5nnB3aVYZSszaoyFZ658WANXD5j3wB)

Answer (score 2):

## [Swift 3](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59792f764877037828e141d9), 147 bytes

-1 thanks to [@Mr.Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder)

```swift
func g(i:[Int]){var r=[Int]();var s=ArraySlice(i);while let e=s.popFirst(){if 0<e&&2<s.count{r+=[0];s=s.dropFirst(2)}else{r+=[e,1]}};print(r+[1])}
```

Ungolfed, returning the value rather than printing:

```swift
func iterate(state: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var result = [Int]()
    
    var inputSlice = ArraySlice(state)
    
    while let element = inputSlice.popFirst() {
        if 0 < element && 2 < inputSlice.count { 
            result += [0]
            inputSlice = inputSlice.dropFirst(2)
        }
        else {
            result += [element, 1]
        }
        
        //debugPrint(result.map(String.init).joined(separator: ""))
    }
    
    return result + [1]
}
```

Comment: You can replace `3<=s.count` with `2<s.count` for *-1 bytes*.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Thanks! I can also detects `1`s in the input with `0 < element` rather than `element == 0`

Answer (score 2):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 70 bytes

```
import re,sugar
x=>x.multiReplace([(re"1..","0"),(re"(.)","$#1")])&"1"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVBLCoMwEN17iiEtJQEJzlawh@i2dCESbcAYSSJ4@zR2UZzp7j3eb5jFurwGP0CUYwtfJPcWYgp2mdQPQFcBmOHtYQQhTrg5EyQKYUiMTcOsVEUWpSOsmGbxL8vC/Czk5bydnVYMx0a2bvUhQTB13KY@VFHu3X3XbpuTfZh17gcjnzIYgVqLuvxJ1QeTWhV2vaBQL3UrH1M5fwA)

`multiReplace` allows us to do substitutions simultaneously. The index of the tuple within the sequence acts as the priority if there is a situation where more than one substitution can be made. The priority rises the lower the index is.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 62 + 2 (`-F`) = 64 bytes

```perl
$r.=$F[$i]&&$i+2<@F&&($i+=2)?0:"$F[$i]1";++$i<@F&&redo;say$r.1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1@lSM9WxS1aJTNWTU0lU9vIxsFNTU0DyLI10rQ3sFKCyBkqWWtrq2SCJYtSU/KtixMrgToN//83MDQwMPyXX1CSmZ9X/F/X11QPKPJf1w0A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 81 bytes

**Both input and output are lists** (thanks to Erik the Outgolfer)

```python
def f(Z):return Z and((1>Z[0]or 3>len(Z))and[Z[0],1]+f(Z[1:])or[0]+f(Z[3:]))or[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNI0rTqii1pLQoTyFKITEvRUPD0C4q2iA2v0jB2C4nNQ8orwkUjgaJ6RjGagM1RBtaxWrmFwEFwDxjIA/ENYz9X1CUmVcCNDPaQEfBUEcBQiJQrCYXQgUyB0UGRRWaLpChsZr/AQ)

**Some cases**

```python
[0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1] --> [0,1,0,0,1,1,1]
[0] ----------------> [0,1,1]
[1] ----------------> [1,1,1]
[] -----------------> [1]
[0,1] --------------> [0,1,1,1,1]
[1,0] --------------> [1,1,0,1,1]
```

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 85 bytes

**Both input and output are strings** (initial solution)

```python
def f(Z):return Z and(('0'==Z[0]or 3>len(Z))and Z[0]+'1'+f(Z[1:])or'0'+f(Z[3:]))or'1'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYwxCsMwDEX3nkKbbLxYyRZID2KToRCHFIochDv09I7cJbG299//On5lzzzUuqYNNhPsJKl8hSHAi1dj0OM8h@iXLDA@P4m1YtVAyxwSOh1FmhabRbt/GpUaEtZD3lz0L3ry1A7t48ru0Jmu1RnSUT0B)

**Some cases**

```python
'01011111'--> 0100111
'0'---------> 011
'1'---------> 111
''----------> 1
'01'--------> 01111
'10'--------> 11011
```

**Explication** It is simplily a golf of a recursive method.

Comment: [Using lists](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNI0rTqii1pLQoTyFKITEvRUPDwNY2KtogNr9IwdguJzUPqEATKB4NEtMxjNUG6og2tIrVzC8CCoB5xkAeiGsY@7@gKDOvBGhotIGOgqGOAoREoFhNLoQKZA6KDIoqNF0gQ2M1/wMA) is shorter.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer thanks :)

Comment: Oh, and you can do `1>Z[0]` instead of `0==Z[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 47 bytes

This is a direct port of the sample implementation Haskell code.

```ruby
f=->s{s=~/^1../??0+f[$']:s=~/./?$&+?1+f[$']:?1}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboWN_XTbHXtiquLbev04wz19PTt7Q2006JV1GOtQEJAvoqatr0hVMjesBaibX2BQlq0koGhgSEIKMVCRGGGAgA)

### More readable

`$&` is the matched text from the previous regexp match (`=~`) and `$'` is the text after the match.

```ruby
f = ->s{
  if s =~ /^1../ then "0" + f[$']
  elsif s =~ /./ then $& + "1" + f[$']
  else "1"
  end
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), <s>69</s> 65 bytes

```julia
~s=s>""?s<"1"?"01"*~s[2:end]:length(s)>2?"0"*~s[4:end]:s*"11":"1"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU87CsJAEO1zCnlVkmomiMWiifeQFILBRJZVnIjdXn2zKurMVI/3ZS4PPx03KUXZSQt0sgWjAzHqKIfGDeHUOz@E8zyWUrVNlt7K@qNIDWa4nEl7Ga/PVcxR4tehuN2nMPtQVsVXww/RH7JiFU2KZ203fh3QCWJTZbp0mVmxM/mnBQ)

Ungolfed and commentated algorithm:

```julia
function ~(s)

  # Return "1" on the empty string
  # (End case for automata ending in "0" or "1..")
  if s == ""
    return "1"

  # "0" always becomes "01"
  elseif s[1] == '0'
    return "01" * ~s[2:end]
  
  # "1.." always becomes "0"
  elseif length(s) > 2
    return "0" * ~s[4:end]

  # Otherwise, append "11"
  # (End case for automata ending in "1" or "1.")
  else return s * "11"

  end
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBBa4QwFITv/oohPayWsiRL6aGwpZeeC70ue0g1rikaxURkL/51@6J1m9BLA4E4mfnGvK@h1vJpnsvB5E63BlNqsyQB7vCh3NAbMMFAuqsUVNO5K6zrtbkslvTNFMilVSjbHnJwbSOdhDIFOaApzCncE2O/ZxlFdAmL4xGM0QfQ3yrWSm@X9SivFp8qbxtlSRLeq2qrfPgkzj6/47sIQCbcY7KnwzOVn@lu5fnev8QAWCtzcRW9GS84xMgf4uNKXHjvNIV@1FY9QHYd6dSw/N5/RiG2USyT8P1bl6WmBeR1UyS051dbtSMmehkXfrGko7G72qRZst2x24n/HkWgBjIPdBHaI38YCBNcRKiIFcKilrhGsPkb)

- -3 bytes thanks to MarcMush: Test the value of `s` instead of `s[1]`
- -1 byte thanks to MarcMush: Rewrite with `s>""` instead of `s==""`

Comment: [65 bytes](https://tio.run/##VU87CsJAEO1zCnlVkmomiMWiifeQFILBRJZVnIjdXn2zKurMVI/3ZS4PPx03KUXZSQt0sgWjAzHqKIfGDeHUOz@E8zyWUrVNlt7K@qNIDWa4nEl7Ga/PVcxR4tehuN2nMPtQVsVXww/RH7JiFU2KZ203fh3QCWJTZbp0mVmxM/mnBQ "Julia 0.6 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 131+29=160 bytes

This is inside a function taking the string `a` as parameter and returning the output as a string.

```scala
var s=""
var k=0
for(c<-0 to a.length-1)breakable{if(k>0){k-=1
break}
if(a(c)==49&c<a.length-3){s+="0"
k+=2}else s+=a(c)+"1"}
s+"1"
```

I do have to `import util.control.Breaks._`, so I need to add those 28 bytes plus a trailing linefeed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BTgQhEETP9ld0OBjIZCagXjTLJnr35AcYhmVWBIEAGhPCt48zRrcv1XmpSlXRyqvVfqSYK35W6ycdQ83RT0/ZKFemV4A4vxtd8VnZgOa7mnAq@JhSg6uTWTDlqE0pVD281GzDmf2pbOuXylgkIbA/TnJYYqb6MHKsEdXkTTjXt1Gwea9SszfNLtQdOWtulAJ@cYeNKaqZlHf31/pwid2yVgZJOAE3yJtufDG4gd06EEE6lF3WDpC2OdUHSrjgYj8cj0iG/@EXTBiDvv4A)

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 108 bytes

```cs
n=>{var t="";for(int i=0,b=n.Length;i<b;){if(n[i]>'0'&i+2<b){t+="0";i+=3;}else t+=n[i++]+"1";}return t+"1";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYsxT8MwEIV3/wrLA7XlUjkwOs6CxFQGxNCh6pAYN5wUzpJ9qYSs/PaQphsC3g1P9973fL73MYV5zIA9f/vKFD4t80ObM38tLFNL4Pklwjt/aQGlKux5RF9nSstge7OmdzO6plzaxMkJYc8xSUDi4My2c7jbB@zpw0LdWVXgLPEIp2ZjNnegH@pOFdJOGGFBu0c7hSEHviQLpPVJi0rYKQUaEy7p@s2WsaeIOQ5hd0hAYQ8YZC@FqYyprhJK2d@Ryvy4f9C/K7Nq7Sc2zd8)

Input taken as a string, and a string is returned as output.